# Calculation to get "PublicKeyToken" from a public key seems to contradict ECMA-335

Tags: c#, .net, hash, sha1

I need to programmatically create the .NET `PublicKeyToken` from any given public key. Now, section 6.3 of the [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_5th_edition_december_2010.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A298%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C69%2C198%2C0%5D) standard states the following about how `PublicKeyToken` is to be calculated:

> The low 8 bytes of the SHA-1 hash of the originator's public key.

With those instructions I set out to write the following method:

```cs
public static string GetPublicKeyToken(byte[] publicKey)
{
  using (var sha1 = SHA1.Create())
  {
    var publicKeyHash = sha1.ComputeHash(publicKey);
    var publicKeyToken = new StringBuilder(16);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
       publicKeyToken.Append(publicKeyHash[i].ToString("x2"));
    }

    return publicKeyToken.ToString();
  }
}
```

To test the method, I'm using the following public key:

```cs
var publicKey = new byte[160] { 0, 36, 0, 0, 4, 128, 0, 0, 148, 0, 0, 0, 6, 2, 0, 0, 0, 36, 0, 0, 82, 83, 65, 49, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 121, 191, 60, 215, 5, 6, 37, 199, 18, 215, 166, 85, 224, 129, 164, 160, 163, 111, 82, 127, 149, 231, 69, 204, 27, 58, 137, 42, 212, 7, 88, 195, 89, 221, 169, 1, 63, 103, 25, 169, 186, 47, 113, 156, 15, 213, 27, 16, 14, 203, 95, 12, 246, 198, 239, 188, 175, 91, 226, 216, 216, 147, 227, 75, 134, 190, 129, 56, 169, 242, 29, 205, 12, 211, 166, 142, 138, 120, 79, 239, 229, 155, 216, 159, 248, 41, 41, 232, 96, 92, 239, 194, 14, 36, 178, 82, 8, 180, 163, 80, 4, 108, 131, 222, 91, 249, 231, 164, 116, 37, 84, 128, 15, 53, 40, 50, 124, 233, 40, 112, 69, 239, 74, 8, 34, 34, 183, 228 };
```

The expected `PublicKeyToken` for that public key is `091b960f069954ca`. That is expected because that is the actual `PublicKeyToken` that I'm getting when signing an assembly with the private key associated with the mentioned public key.

However, the method shown above does not return that expected result. After some trial and error I figured that if I extract the last 8 bytes and not the first 8 bytes I'm getting the correct result. The implementation in that case would look as follows:

```cs
public static string GetPublicKeyTokenMod(byte[] publicKey)
{
  using (var sha1 = SHA1.Create())
  {
    var publicKeyHash = sha1.ComputeHash(publicKey);
    var publicKeyToken = new StringBuilder(16);

    for (int i = publicKeyHash.Length - 1; i >= publicKeyHash.Length - 8; i--)
    {
       publicKeyToken.Append(publicKeyHash[i].ToString("x2"));
    }

    return publicKeyToken.ToString();
  }
}
```

That implementation returns the correct result. But I don't understand why. x86, x86_64, ARM, etc. all use little endian and so my understanding is that the first implementation should be the correct one.

Does anyone know why I need to read the last 8 bytes instead of the first?

Comment: Docs say "last 8 bytes": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.applicationid.publickeytoken?view=net-7.0. And I would also expect last 8 bytes, since usually when you mention low bytes without specifying big or little endian - it means rightmost bytes. There is no reason here it should depend on endianess of x86 or any other architecture.

Comment: Good point with that link and your remarks. I think I really just misinterpreted what they meant by "low" in the standard.